# Что это за кодировка такая?

Tags: php

Лазил по одному скрипту для телеги, в поисках текста копирайта. В итоге оказалось что копирайт был как-то зашифрован, что ли.
Вместо Bot By там было написано вот это:

> Erw#E|

Скрипт написан на php. уж больно интересно что это за шифр такой. вот та часть кода в которой он был вписан:

```
define('A9029', array(
    'A' => 3,
   '9029' => 'Erw#E|#CQrlow|'
));
```

Позже фрагмент 'A9029' встречался вовремя отправки сообщения в телегу:

```
tgBotMessage($sRandomName, openKey(A9029['9029'], A9029['A']), MESSAGE);
```

Функция openKey:

```
function openKey($text, $current)
{
    $sResult = '';

    for($i=0; $i < strlen($text); $i++) {
        $symbol = ord($text[$i]) - $current;

        if($symbol < $current) {
            $symbol = 255 - $current;
        }
        $sResult .= chr($symbol);
    }

    return $sResult;
}
```

уж больно интересно что это.
И если кто знает, как закодировать так же другой текст)
Спасибо.

Comment: `openKey` - функция расшифровки. Первый параметр зашифрованный текст, второй - ключ расшифровки. Алгоритм просто сдвигает код символа на величину ключа. https://ideone.com/Ro1UEn

Comment: @MaximTimakov Спасибо за ответ!
остается только последний вопрос: как произвести то же самое с другим текстом? т.е. заменить Erw#E|#CQrlow| на свой текст, в таком же виде

Answer (score 0):

```php
<?php

function encode($text, $current)
{
    $sResult = '';

    for($i=0; $i < strlen($text); $i++) {
        $chr = ord($text[$i]) + $current;
        $sResult .= chr($chr);
    }

    return $sResult;
}
```